# Openshift 3 Socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

I have uploaded a site in openshift, everything seems to be working except socket io.
I can see the network tab that polling is taking place but no action is happening.
Here is my server side socket code

```
port= process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080

io = require('socket.io').listen(applisten);
    io.configure(function(){
      io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
   });
```

and below is my client side code to connectto socket.io

```
socket = io.connect("http://something:8000");
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue after socket.io changed to version 1.0.

Here's the changes that will make it work again:

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(applisten);
io.set('transports', [ 'polling', 'websocket' ]);
```

On client side:

```
socket = io();
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, another side effect from the changes I realised from the changes was that this function does not work:

```
socket.on('connect', function(data){
});
```

I change the keyword 'connect' to another something else and it works.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for help Adrian, but it doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: try removing "websocket" under transports. I did that and seems to work for me.